# How to solve archive pagination 404 error wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I working on pagination for custom taxonomy archive page in wordpress. When i am going to page 2 it give me 404 error. My setting "Blog pages show at most value is 10" But in my archive page have only two values. Each page i want to display one post. How can i solve this. This is my code.

```
$args = array(                        
  'post_type' => array(
  'post',
   'projects',
    'storefronts',
    'pressreleases',
    'products',
    'videos',
     'whitepapers',
   'industryopinion'
 ),
  'tax_query' => array(
       array( 
        'taxonomy' => 'industry_taxonomy',
        'field' => 'slug',
         'terms' => $term
         )
      ),
       'posts_per_page' => 1, 
       'paged'          => $paged                        
        );



 <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                    <div class="pagination">
                    <?php 
                     previous_posts_link( 'Older Posts' );
                   next_posts_link( 'Newer Posts', $loop->max_num_pages );                   
                    ?>
```

Comment: What is the slug of the page? You can't have a page with the same slug as a custom post type and expect pagination to work.

Comment: Have you refreshed your permalinks?

Comment: Yes i refreshed permalinks? when i changed Blog pages show at most value is 1 then it will working.